# Persisting data from local storage from React/Redux to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, react-redux, airflow

I have a React based web application that is  currently using local storage through redux reducers/store. I'm looking to push the data to a specific Project in Google Cloud Platform but I'm not entirely sure where to start, would I be doing it via an API call, uploading JSON or is there a way to utilise Airflow to load data into GCP

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you need to ask yourself wheather you want to run your app in a VM as a container, in the App Engine or in a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs).**

Based on that you take appropriate steps.

First of all you need to set up a GCP account and create a project. That's a good start since you want to make some test probably and then put it to the production.

**If you decide to contenerise your app you can [push it to the Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling)** and deploy it from there to App Engine or Compute Engine. You can even run it in Kubernetes Cluster.

If you're more familiar with Github use it - it's also a viable solution.

Here's a tutorial how to [deploy React app into Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/deploy-react-nginx-cloud-run). Try going through fallowing articles to have better idea on this topic:

- [Deploying a React App to Google Cloud Run With GitHub Actions](https://medium.com/swlh/deploying-a-react-app-to-google-cloud-run-with-github-actions-ae24ac6cb85a)
- [5 Step Guide To Deploy Your React App On Google’s App Engine](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/quickly-deploy-your-react-app-on-googles-app-engine-6bb97480cc9c)

**If you decide to go with App Engine** here's some [quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) describing the steps.

**One of the least efficient way to run your container is Compute Engine VM instance** - [here's how it works](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers).

**At the very end there's [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app)** which will allow you full scalability if that's what you'll need in the forseable future.

If you provide more details to you question I may be able to give you more refined answer.